# JQuery callback from Pusher Event -- Strange Occurrence

Tags: jquery, html, pusher

I'm using Pusher as a requests counter on my site.

I have two browser windows open, window 'A' in chrome and window 'B' in incognito mode.

I both are subscribed to a requestChannel on pusher, and whenever an event happens on the channel, my javascript console logs the data and i use JQuery to $selector.html(data).

when window A has the site open and I visit the site via window B,the console properly logs the data updates the html. **BUT** when i visit another page in window A, only the console.log works in window B! the html doesnt update with jquery.

I have no idea why this is happening. The log is fine; both windows notice and fire the event properly.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: To clarify: are you saying that the events are being received by their intended client? Is it simply that the `$selector.html(data)` call isn't having the desired result? If so, this is either a `jQuery` issue (unlikely) or the selector isn't matching any elements. In this case providing more code demonstrating your problem would be useful. Or, better still a link to a sample that shows the problem.

Comment: The $selector.html(data) IS having the desired call. I make the event call from window A, the event is called in window B and everything works as expected and as it should. then, i call the event from window B. Window A receives the event, as i can see it through the log, NOW the $selector.html(data) doesnt work.